# What commands in virsh corresponds to "Force Off" button in virt-manager?

Tags: libvirt, virt-manager, virsh

I'm trying to find the corresponding command to the buttons in virt-manager,

I read about `virsh help domain` and I found start, shutdown and reset etc. But the one for `Force Off` is missing.

Anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`virsh destroy`, from `man virsh`

```
Immediately terminate the domain domain.  
This doesn't give the domain OS any chance to react, 
and it's the equivalent of ripping the power cord out on a physical machine.
```

Comment: This is confusing to me (and probably the OP hence the question). Destroy seems like you're deleting the VM.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat considering that the answer was accepted years ago, it probably wasn't confusing to the OP. if you think ripping out a power cord deletes a physical machine, then i can understand the confusion though.

Answer (score 0):

`virsh reset domain` is what you need,

```
$ man virsh|grep "reset domain" -A5 -B4
   reset
       Syntax:

          reset domain

       Reset a domain immediately without any guest shutdown. reset emulates the power reset button on a machine, where all guest hardware sees the RST line set and reinitializes inter‐nal state.

       Note: Reset without any guest OS shutdown risks data loss.
```